# Online course about distance measures

Tags: references, distance, distance-functions

With the increasing amount of unstructured data distance measures get more and more important. I am looking for an online course or any other material which gives me a profound inside in the following areas

**Distances based on edits**

- Damerau-Levenshtein
- Hamming
- Levenshtein
- Optimal sting alignment

**Distances based on qgrams**

- qgram
- cosine
- jaccard distance

**Distances based on or heuristic metrics**

- Jaro
- Jaro-Winkler

**Distances based on quantitative computations**

- Geometric
- Manhattan

As well as the theoretical concepts of distance measures and distance functions and **applications** such as

- String comparison
- Fuzzy matching
- Clustering

Edit: Any implementations in `R` such as the `agrep` / `agrepl` function and the `stringdist` package are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly I do not think that such narrowly focused course exists anywhere (online or offline), but there is an [*Encyclopedia of Distances*](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642002342) book by Deza and Deza (2009, Springer) that you could check.